# Python Pandas: How to find element in a column with a matching string object of other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this string object:

```
code = '1002'
```

And i also have the following Pandas Data Frame:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Code':['1001','1002','1003','1004'],
              'Place':['Chile','Peru','Colombia','Argentina']})
```

What i need is to match the code i hace as a stirng with the column 'Code' and get the element in the same row from the column 'Place'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `set_index` first, if you want to get the actual value:

```
>>> df.set_index('Code').loc['1002', 'Place']
'Peru'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['1001','1002','1003','1004'],
              'Place':['Chile','Peru','Colombia','Argentina']})

code = '1002'
df.loc[df['Code'] == code, 'Place'].iloc[0]
```

```
Peru
```

Or

```
df[df['Code'] == code]['Place']
```

Answer (score 0):

basically to solve this u have to get the index of the code first, after converting data frame value into list, I think my following code might help u.

```
 import pandas as pd
 code = '1001'
 df = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['1001','1002','1003','1004'],
          'Place':['Chile','Peru','Colombia','Argentina']})

 code_index = list(df['Code']).index(code)
 print(code_index)
 area = df['Place'][code_index]
 print(area)
```